# plot a line between two points in subplot matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot

I want to plot a line between two subplot points, but I don't know how to point them.
I had this as an idea, but it throws an error.

```
plot(subplot(1,2,1),[1 2],subplot(1,2,2),[3 4]);
```

Comment: Do you have a diagram of what you mean exactly by a line between two subplots?

Answer (score 0):

### Plotting a Red Line Between Subplots:

Below is a line that's drawn using the `annotation()` function. This function can have several input properties such as `arrow` or `line` that indicate the shape the annotation takes. You can edit the positions/coordinates of the line by adjusting `X` and `Y` below.

[image: Red Line Between Subplots]

```
clf;
subplot(1,2,1); plot([1 2]);
subplot(1,2,2); plot([3 4]);
X = [0.465,0.57];
Y = [0.48,0.48];

Line_Annotation = annotation('line',X,Y);
Line_Annotation.LineWidth = 3;
Line_Annotation.Color = 'red';
```

---

### Plotting a Red Line Between Two Subplot Points:

[image: Line Between Two Subplot Points]

```
clf;
subplot(1,2,1); plot([1 2]);
subplot(1,2,2); plot([3 4]);
X = [0.282,0.792];
Y = [0.48,0.65];

Line_Annotation = annotation('line',X,Y);
Line_Annotation.LineWidth = 1;
Line_Annotation.Color = 'red';
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: in annotation X and Y must be between [0,1] ,my plots are image and I want to draw a line between pixels with the coordinate witch I have in two images.

Comment: Yes, that’s true since annotation is a fraction/decimal relative to the figure size.

Comment: so how to convert coordinates of pixels to [0 1] ?

Comment: One method could be to size the figures and subplots using their Position property then calculate everything accordingly but that be a great deal of work. Trial and error works if your only planning to do a few lines.

Comment: You might want to consider putting both images in a single plot then using the line function maybe a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it must be drew with subplot.